# flash based game stopped loading

Tags: web, flash

A few weeks ago our flash based game at www.balutgame.com suddenly stopped loading, which was working fine earlier. The website it self loads, but the game window does not, all users just get a black screen.

We have made no changes to the game, DNS etc. According to our hosting company, PLayerIO, the page and files load, however the game file does not.

Since the web version is flash based, I am wondering if it is necessary to make ongoing updates to the swf file when Adobe make updates to their flash player?
I do not know if we have used Adobe Air as well in the web version, but know this is used somehow in app versions we have.

Our problem is isolated to the webversion www.balutgame.com. Hosted at PlayerIO and domain registered with name.com
How to Fix this?

Comment: Try asking this on [Super User](http://superuser.com/). If you don't have a question about a specific piece of code, they are probably better suited to answer questions about general software issues.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information of this question, it is hard to provide any solution.
I did run a few test on your site and figured the play button is linked to a swf file.
It points to `http://d1ro1du4c73r1c.cloudfront.net/balut-dq1cn30nkeozclazbnk7q/Balut%20Web/Balut._v3.swf` this swf file i think needs some player/wrapper for other dependent functionalities.

Have you updated your web page recently? Also FB plugins never loads!
You can check that as well.